# Objective C - Load JSON from .php file

Tags: php, json, xcode, load

I'm making in a app in xCode. I have a method that is loading JSON data from a .json file. This works fine, my viewcontroller shows me the JSON objects (after parsing). The code is:

```
- (void) loadJsonData
{
//Create an URL
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www....json"];

//Sometimes servers return a wrong header. Use this to add a new accepted type
[AFJSONRequestOperation addAcceptableContentTypes:[NSSet setWithObject:@"application/x-javascript"]];

//Create a request object with the url
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

//Create the JSON operation. The ^ blocks are executed when loading is done.
AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request     success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {

    //Do something with the JSON data, like parsing
    [self parseJSONData:JSON];
    } failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id JSON) {
    //Do something with the error
    NSLog(@"Error :%@",response);

}];

//Start the operation
[operation start];
}
```

But now i want use the JSON objects from a existing .php file. I change the URL in "http:// www .... .php". I got no errors, but it doesn't load the JSON. My viewcontroller doesn't show the data. I tried to change many things in the code, but nothing works. Can somebody help me with the exact code for the loadJsonData if i use a .php instead of .json url.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I hope it will help you.

---

I am using following function in my project.

At first getting json string from `PHP` as following

```
-(NSString *)httpRequest:(NSURL *)url {

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    NSString *userAgent = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"myProject-IOS"];
    [request setValue:userAgent forHTTPHeaderField:@"User-Agent"];

    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"content-type"];

    [request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];

    [request setTimeoutInterval:25];

    NSURLResponse *response;

    NSData *dataReply = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:nil];

    NSString *stringReply = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataReply encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

    return stringReply;
}

NSString *link = @"http://domain.com/mypage.php";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",link]];
NSString *response = [NSString stringWithString:[R httpRequest:url]];
```

After getting json string parsing it using [SBSON](http://jasarien.com/?p=428) to NSDictionary as following

```
-(NSMutableDictionary *) parse:(NSString *)str {
    SBJSON *parser = [[SBJSON alloc] init];
    NSMutableDictionary *results = [parser objectWithString:str error:nil];
    //[parser release];

    return results;
}

NSDictionary *results = [R parse:response];
```

My PHP page looks like as following

```
<?php

$array = array();

$array1 = array("a"=>"A", "b"=>"B", "c"=>"C");
$array2 = array("x"=>"X", "y"=>"X", "z"=>"Z");
$array3 = array("p"=>"P", "q"=>"Q", "r"=>"R");

$array[] = $array1;
$array[] = $array2;
$array[] = $array3;

echo json_encode($array);

?>
```